# How to run multiple Node.js sites (apps/servers) with separate SSL cert's, on a single IP address?

Tags: dns, multiple-domains, webserver, node-js, reverse-proxy

The desired scenario is as the title suggests: Multiple Node.js servers/apps/websites, on separate domains, each with own SSL certificate, on a single server with a single IP address. So far I have tried:

- **A proxy** catching all incoming requests and forwarding them to respective apps/servers, on separate, non-443 ports: Does not work, since the proxy server can only run on a single SSL certificate, which will throw an error for all but one of the domains.
- **Apps running on different ports and [DNS pointing at these ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports)**: Does not work, since an HTTPS connection, will always go to port 443. The SRV DNS record can't change this, for ports 443 and 80.
- **Using a single SSL cert issued for an IP address**: Is somehow possible, but after doing some research on this, it is not such a good idea.
- **Servers responding to specific hostnames**: `httpsServer.listen(443,'domain.name')` throws `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 123.456.789.000:443`. This is where I expected the server to ignore all requests but those where hostname is the domain.name. But still, you can't run multiple servers on a single port.

So back to square one: what I need is a proxy, which establishes a connection with an SSL certificate for the specific requested hostname, and forwards the request to an app/server running on a unique port. How? EDIT: Using Nginx, or other proxy/firewall software is certainly an option, but at this point, I am trying to find out a Node.js-only solution.

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thank you, @Maxmilian Lauermeister. I forgot to mention, that at this point, I am trying to find out a Node.js-only solution, if there is one.

Comment: There is no reason for a node.js only solution.  It is very common to run Nginx, Apache, or a load balancer in front of several backend web servers that each handle one site.   Any of those three will handle multiple SSL certificates for different sites and forward requests to the back end servers correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [redbird](https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird), a Node.js reverse proxy. Your config will look something like this

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});

proxy.register("example1.com", "http://127.0.0.1:8001", {
  ssl: {
    letsencrypt: {
      email: 'john@example.com', // Domain owner/admin email
      production: true, // WARNING: Only use this flag when the proxy is verified to work correctly to avoid being banned!
    }
  }
});

proxy.register("example2.com", "http://127.0.0.1:8002", {
  ssl: {
    letsencrypt: {
      email: 'john@example.com', // Domain owner/admin email
      production: true, // WARNING: Only use this flag when the proxy is verified to work correctly to avoid being banned!
    }
  }
});
```